# Google sheets api to create table chart

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to create a table chart in google sheets using google sheets apis. 
What I was able to do is I can create basi charts, pie charts, bubble charts but can't find any reference for table-chart.
Is there any api for this?

Comment: Does [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) help you?

Comment: I think Google visualization api is for webpages. I actually want to create table chart directly in sheets with my data. So that I can link that chart in google slide.